# About the maximum number of ordinary points on algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDoublePoint.html

I'm trying to figure out the (3) statement ( $\mu(d)\leq \frac{1}{2}(d(d-1)-3) $ )

That can't be true if the table bellow it is correct (and it is)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it seems that everybody on the internet is wrong about the equation, it is:
$\mu (d)\leq \frac{1}{2} (d(d-1)^2-3)$